# Alinear un encabezado <h1> con css

Tags: html, css

**Hola, estoy intentando alinear un h1 en el centro de la pantalla con css3 en la misma posición horizontal en la que se encuentra. Este es el html y el css que tengo, agradezco la ayuda :)**

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#castillo {
    display: block;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
h1 {
    margin: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>Draco </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>DRACOS</h1>
    <img src="img/castle.jpg" alt="castillo" id="castillo">
    <main>
        
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.h1__dracos{
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<h1 class="h1__dracos">DRAKOS</h1>
```

Hola Santiago yo tambien soy nuevo pero creo que lo que necesitas hacer es ponerle una clase al h1 como por ejemplo:

```
<h1 class="h1__dracos">DRAKOS</h1>
```

y despues ir a tus estilos css y escribir:

```
.h1__dracos{
  text-align: center
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, creo que te refieres al tema de la especificidad

Answer (score 0):

Basta com quitarle la propiedad `position: absolute;` y agregar la propiedad `text-align: center;` a la etiqueta `h1` en los estilos `CSS`

De acuerdo con la [documentación en w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

> Un elemento con `position: absolute;` se coloca en relación con el ancestro posicionado más cercano. Sin embargo, si un elemento con posición absoluta no tiene ancestros con posición, utiliza el cuerpo del documento y se mueve junto con el desplazamiento de la página.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#castillo {
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <title>Draco </title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>DRACOS</h1>
  <img src="img/castle.jpg" alt="castillo" id="castillo">
  <main>

  </main>
</body>

</html>
```